# proper syntax in system.out.prinln()

Tags: java

Today started learning Java and I need help to clear my doubt.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner leo = new Scanner(System.in);
        double f, s;
        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        f = leo.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        s = leo.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("The sum is " + f + s);
    }
}
```

When I write `+f+s` then both are treated as `String`.

```
Enter first number: 2
Enter second number: 5
The sum is 2.05.0
```

But when I write `(f+s)` then they are treated as `doubles` (which is the desired result).

```
Enter first number: 3
Enter second number: 4
The sum is 7
```

Why does that happen?

Also why do we write the line `import java.util.Scanner` before the `class JavaAapplication1`?

P.S. Is this series of videos [Video Link](https://thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=31&video=17972%20good%20for%20learning%20java) good for learning Java?

Comment: Its not considered as string. since + operator is evaluated from left to right it first adds your string and first number and then adds the second number to the result string.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant source code as text within the question. Don't link to code (or pictures of code) on another site.

Comment: `import` is required to use `Scanner` without its package name. The compiler will “replace” all references to `Scanner` with `java.util.Scanner`. You can drop `import` and just use `java.util.Scanner` in local variable declaration and object instantiation.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that what matters is the order of operation

In

```
System.out.println("The sum is:"+f+s)
```

The first operation is `"The sum is:"+f` so the + operator takes a string and a double as operands and the f variable is cast to its string value. Then second + operator takes "The sum is:2"+0.5 and again we have a conversion from double to string.

However, in

```
System.out.println("The sum is:"+(f+s))
```

We first have f+s calcualted which is an addition between two doubles followed by a concatenation.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

It is the [BODMAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) rule which stands for Brackets, Orders, Division, Multiplication, Addition, Subtraction

Since you dont add them in brackets, it adds(concatenates) the string. It evaluates everything within the bracket

```
("string" + f + s)
```

Unless you specifically add brackets

```
("string" + (f + s))
```

In this case, the inner brackets are evaluated first and then the outer.

> Also why do we write the line import java.util.scanner before the
>   class java application 1?

In order to use the imported stuff in the class, you need to import before class, so the compiler knows.